# Do the following sentences sound incorrect?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, grammaticality

We use **'also' / 'too' / 'as well'** in **affirmative** sentences, and **'either'** in **negative** sentences to give more information about someone or something.

> 1. *"Jane speaks French. Peter also speaks French."*
> 2. *"Jane speaks French. Peter speaks French too."*
> 3. *"Peter speaks French. He speaks French as well."*
> 4. *"Jane doesn't speak French. Peter doesn't speak French either."*

**But do the following sentences [5, 6 & 7]  sound incorrect?**  (I think, as per the rules of grammar, they're incorrect, but they sound good to my ears.)

> 5. *"You are not a doctor. I am **also not** a doctor."* [Instead of *"You are not a doctor. I am not a doctor either".*]
> 6. *"You don't know it. **I, too, don't know** it."* [Instead of *"You don't know it. I don't know it either."*]
> 7. *"Russian is not easy. English is **not easy as well**."* [Instead of *"Russian is not easy. English is not easy either."*]

Comment: Sandip, this is asking us to do your homework. We don't answer a whole series of questions on this site. If you have a query, you need to tell us what you have done to find the answer and what you think it is.

Comment: I've found the rules of grammar that I've mentioned. As per the grammar, those sentences (5, 6, 7) are incorrect; but they don't sound incorrect to my ear. So, I would like to hear from a native whether they're correct or not.

Comment: You are looking for neither am I, neither do I  and neither is English.

Comment: Excuse me? Those are suggestions for answering 5, 6 and 7. For example  "you are not a doctor "Neither am I". You are being rude.

Comment: That's another point. Here it's about the usage of also, too, as well in those sentences given.